# How to insert a contact record of particular recordtype while creating parent record?

Tags: trigger, record-type

I have two objects Account&Contact,both objects contain 3 recordtypes India,UK,USA.

Whenever i create a new account with any of these recordtypes a contact should be created automatically with the same recordtype.

i.e If i select recordtype 'India' in account, contact should be created with 'India' recordtype in contact obj. 
If i select 'UK', contact should be created with 'UK' recordtype in contact obj.
If i select 'USA', contact should be created with 'USA' recordtype in contact obj.

I tried the following code but what is the condition that i have to put in for the above senario

Can anyone please provide the code for the above scenario.

```
trigger AccRecTypeTrigger on Account (after insert) {

      //Map<Id,Schema.RecordTypeInfo> m1 = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosById();
   // Id IndiaContactRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Contact.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('India').getRecordTypeId();
    //Id USAContactRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Contact.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('USA').getRecordTypeId();
    //Id UKContactRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Contact.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('UK').getRecordTypeId();

       List<Contact> conlst = new List<Contact>();
       List<RecordType> r = [select id,name from RecordType where SObjectType='Account' and isActive=true];
        Map<Id,String> m = new Map<Id,String>();
            for(RecordType rt : r){
              m.put(rt.id,rt.name);
            }

    for(Account a : trigger.new){
         String name = m.get(a.recordtype.id);
         List<Recordtype> r1  = [select id,name from RecordType where Sobjecttype='Contact' and isActive = true];
          for(RecordType rt : r1){
           if(a.recordtype.name == name){
                Contact con = new Contact(); 
                con.accountId = a.id; 
                con.lastname = a.name;
                con.recordTypeId = rt.id;      
                conlst.add(con);
            }
           }
         }

    insert conlst;

}
```

Comment: It seems like you've asked this question before.

Comment: You keep asking nearly identical questions. How is this one any different than [Using recordtypes of the same name across multiple SObject types](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/133522/using-recordtypes-of-the-same-name-across-multiple-sobject-types)?

Answer (score 1):

I rewrite you trigger to be more easy to read

```
trigger AccRecTypeTrigger on Account (after insert) {

  Map<String,String> rtNameById = new Map<String,String>();
  Map<String,String> rtIdByName = new Map<String,String>();

  for(RecordType rt : [SELECT Id,DeveloperName FROM RecordType WHERE SobjectType = 'Account']){
    rtNameById.put(rt.Id,rt.DeveloperName);
  }

  for(RecordType rt : [SELECT Id,DeveloperName FROM RecordType WHERE SobjectType = 'Contact']){
    rtIdByName.put(rt.DeveloperName,rt.Id);
  }

  Contact[] newContacts = new Contact[]{};
  for(Account a : Trigger.new){
    // This only works if the recordtype USA,Indian.... has the same developerName in Account and Contact
    if(rtIdByName.containKey(rtNameById.get(a.RecordTypeId))){
      newContacts.add(new Contact(
        AccountId = a.Id
        ,LastName = a.name
        ,RecordTypeId = rtIdByName.get(rtNameById.get(a.RecordTypeId));
      ));
    }
  }

  insert newContacts;

}
```

Comment: @Rajendra if it is the answer. can you chose it and close the question?

Answer (score 0):

First things first: you should never put a query inside a loop.

Now to answer your question:
If both accounts and contacts only have these 3 recordtypes and their names are same, you can create a map with key being equal to contact RT name and value contact RT id. For example:

```
Map<String, Id> contactRTNameToIdMap = new Map<String, Id>();
```

Also, query accounts RecordType.Name field(*note*: it is not available in `trigger.new`, so you will have to query it). Then, when you are creating contacts, you can simply `get()` the contacts RT Id based on its' corresponding account RT name.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code, but I haven't complied it so there might be some syntax error. 
Note: never use SOQL statements in a loop because you will hit the 101 SOQL limit very fast

```
 trigger AccRecTypeTrigger on Account (after insert) {
       List<Contact> conlst = new List<Contact>();
       List<RecordType> acc_r = [select id,name from RecordType where SObjectType='Account' and isActive=true];
       List<RecordType> con_r = [select id,name from RecordType where SObjectType='Account' and isActive=true];

        Map<Id,String> acc_m = new Map<Id,String>();
            for(RecordType rt : acc_r){
              acc_m.put(rt.id,rt.name);
            }
          Map<String, Id> con_m = new Map<String, ID>();
            for(RecordType rt : con_r){
              con_m.put(rt.name,rt.id);
            }

   List<Account> newAccounts =[Select id, RecordTypeId, RecordTypeName from Accoutn where id in : Trigger.new.keyset()];

    for(Account a : newAccounts){
         String account_rtn = acc_m.get(a.recordtype.id);
         id contact_rti = con_m.get(account_rtn);

                Contact con = new Contact(); 
                con.accountId = a.id; 
                con.lastname = a.name;
                con.recordTypeId = contact_rti;    
                conlst.add(con);
            }


    insert conlst;

}
```